# Flex ignores 100% width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why does flex ignore the width set on some items, but obey the widths set on others?

I want to use flex for a grid system where sometimes I want items that are 100% in width.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/QNYoYr)

In this linked example I want the items to obey the widths they are give. `.full` should be 100% width across the screen while `.one-third` and `.two-thirds` should obey their respective widths of 33.3% and 66.6%

But instead, everything squeezes onto one line.

```
.grid.full {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid.one-third {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.grid.two-thirds {
  width: 66.66%;
}
```

Comment: I opened your codepen and your full is 100% across (800px), one-third and two-thirds are on the next line.

Comment: What browser are you looking at this in?

Comment: your codepen looks okay, just the way you want it to behave...

Comment: You don't have autoprefixer or prefixfree enabled, so I imagine that you may be running into cross-browser issues.

Comment: The observation by @zzzzBov makes sense. Here are some more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276